# hibernate query with named parameter giving no result

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am facing problem when using hibernate named parameters in spring MVC

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query q = session.createQuery("from Users u where u.username = :name and u.password = :pass");
    q.setParameter("name", username);
    q.setParameter("pass", password);
    Users user = (Users) q.uniqueResult();
```

The output when using log4j is and printing user

```
2017-01-20 22:34:17 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - "test"
2017-01-20 22:34:17 TRACE BasicBinder:83 - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - "test"

user =  null
```

And when I use query like:

```
"from Users u where u.username = 'test' and u.password = 'test'"
```

I get the user values.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you enable show_sql to see the query that was getting fired?

Comment: Yes: it is :select
        users0_.id as id0_,
        users0_.password as password0_,
        users0_.username as username0_ 
    from
        Users users0_ 
    where
        users0_.username=? 
        and users0_.password=?

Comment: Can you change `setParameter` to `setString`? Maybe the issue is with recognizing the type of username and password objects. Are these objects strings?

Comment: Did that ,same result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the hibernate log for `basic-binder`. Your variable `username` and `password` contain two double quotes(at the start and end).

Look at the variables in a debugger or try hardcoding the values in the `setParameter` methods.

Comment: Yeah , I noticed as few minutes ago . Silly me :P. But thanks